# Как убрать отступ под блоком?

Tags: css3, html, css, bootstrap

При перезагрузке страницы изображение ресайзится под ширину браузера и высоту. Непонятно почему внизу контейнера появляется отступ, как его убрать?
Используется bootstrap.

```
html css можно посмотреть здесь http://5ee03865.ngrok.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть поэтому?

```
body .g-wrap-container1 {
  background: url('/image/groups/points_paralax.png') repeat, #141b1e;
  position: absolute;
  height: 980px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Попробуйте поставить `height: 100%` вместо `height: 980px`

**UPD.** А ещё у вас там в анимации когда штора убирается вверх, стоит `top:-1000px`, поменяйте на `top: -100%;`, а то штора на мониторах с разрешением больше 1000px по высоте будет уходить не до конца

Comment: Спасибо, моя внимательность на нуле)